# Echo email from url string

Tags: php

I have a url with this string

```
https://domain.om/index.php/#&state=email%40domain.com
```

I am trying to strip out the email address from the url string but the `$_GET` email function isn’t working.

Can anyone help with how to capture that email from the url string and echo

Comment: It's gonna be in `$_GET['status']`, not `$_GET['email']`, and `$_GET['status']` is gonna have a value of `email=email@domain.don`. Why is your URL like this?

Comment: 0
Down vote
accept
That’s how the email url was encoded and I’m trying to get that email and pass the info to session and DB

But $_GET['status'] is also not working and I guess that should be because of the encoded = and @ in the email

Trying to find away around this

Comment: My best guess is that a `&` is missing when the URL is built and should be like this: `?somethingsomething=...&status=&email=email%40domain.don`

Comment: A var_dump($_GET); might shine some light on what we're working with, add that to your post if you can

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier The `=` in `email=` is encoded, so it's more than just a missing `&`. Somewhere something's been screwed up and it'd be better to fix at the source rather than trying to work around.

Comment: I’m thinking of a way around. Like declaring the encoded characters which is = and @ in php and then echo to form part of the full email later unencoded

Comment: @ceejayoz Assuming the `&`  from `&email` is missing, then the `=` from `email=email%40domain.don` will be encoded as `%3d` as any other char and will result exactly `&status=email%3demail%40domain.don`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I believe he cannot change the input for some reason. That's why I'm asking for a var_dump($_GET). If we get what we're all expecting ie. status => "email=email@domain.don" the problem he's having is string manipulation. If it's still encoded there is a function for that. But without that info we're just shooting in the dark

Comment: As others noted, the issue is that `email` is not a valid field in your URL string. It's actually part of the content of `status`. What you would need to do is extract the contents of `status`, URL decode it, then parse the resulting string.

Comment: After using 
const queryString = window.location.search;

console.log(queryString);

in console of inspect element on the return url string i got no query so that must be why all method aint working. Any otther way i can stripe this info out from the url

Comment: @Bond007 1) Please add the full url (hide the domain if needed) to your question 2) What's generating the URL? Can you modify it? If so, please add this to your question as well. As you can see per the comments, the query string is clearly broken. We cannot help you if you don't provide more information and the question will be closed.

Comment: I just corrected the return query URL. but there is something i noticed. I did echo the full URL on return back to my domain after authentication but it neglect the return URL strings and only echo my domain.com/folder. the URL is generated by oauth authentication through return URL to my domain after authentication.

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: i did try GET function already but not working

Comment: We  already "GET" it ;) But without a comprehensible context nor reproducible example we cannot help you.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the **full** URL? Do hide/replace sensible information though

Comment: Okay the flow is Open ID auth and on return back to my site the query url returns the email with the variable state in the url and i am trying to capture that email which returns as part of the url and pass it to my DB. I did notice there is a "#" symbol right after the index.php to my site
here is the example of return url: https://domain.om/index.php/# &state=email%40domain.com

Comment: You URL is not valid. Right now it's not a query string, it's an anchor to the id `&state=email%40domain.com` (and even this is probably not valid) Also the query string **must** start with `?` and not `&`. So, I'm re-asking: _What's generating the URL? Can you modify it? If so, please add this to your question as well_

Comment: Also, I believe that everything that comes after `#` is client side only

Comment: the url is generated by OpenID authentication and yes anything that comes after the # in the url is not recognized as i did echo the full url and it only stop before the # when it was echoed back using php but in the url address of browser i can see the full url including the after #

Answer (score 0):

you get the content of get by going $_GET["state"] aren't you ?

try :

echo(isset($_GET["state"]));

it will show 1(true) if email is in get and nothing (false) if it isn't.

Also, try to check if you unset / modify the content of $_GET["state"] in your code.

Finally, if you wanna say that you email isn't in the good format, that is because it is url encoded.
You can decide it and get the full email with the function urldecode.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

EDIT :
$_GET may decode the string automatically.
(See comment bellow)

Comment: i think GET function automatically decode and no need to use decode function again